# Performance penalty of nearly static second screen

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop running a GT 650M with an external 1920x1080 display and a built in 1600x900 screen.

Is there a measurable penalty to leaving the inbuilt screen on while gaming on the external display from a graphics performance perspective? or, to put it differently, is there a benefit to switching to single monitor mode every time I start a game?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just still and on the desktop as you said, then a few FPS (1-2 FPS). But nothing bad at all.

This is just from general experience from when I did the same (apart from mine was a GTX 550ti) - which is still old now.